# ASP.NET: HttpRuntime.Cache getting flushed when saving WebConfigurationManager -- Is this a bug?

Tags: asp.net, caching, webconfigurationmanager, httpruntime.cache

Recently, I've been experimenting with caching objects with `HttpRuntime.Cache` and I was generally under the impression that if I "added" something to the cache like this:

```
HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert("Test", "This is a test!", null, 
     Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, 
     CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable, new CacheItemRemovedCallback(FileChanged));
```

that the "NotRemovable" and "NoExpiration" flags would keep the object in-memory for the duration of the application. But was finding that at the end of certain page requests, the HttpRuntime.Cache would be completely empty!

Tracing thru and setting a breakpoint inside my Callback "FileChanged" I could see that indeed something was "removing" my object (and every other object in the cache), but I couldn't figure out why. So eventually, I started disabling other things that I thought might affect this subsystem.

Eventually, I commented out the line:

```
WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~").Save;
```

I had been mostly retrieving data from "web.config" in the AppSettings region, but occasionally writing back to AppSettings and saving the changes using the above command. I knew from reading that the "web.config" is cached, but saving my changes back to it shouldn't flush all of HttpRuntime.Cache, right?

Is this a bug? Or are the two caches somehow linked in a way that I should be made aware of?

**EDIT:**

Ok, I've made this super reproducible if anyone wants to try this on their own machine. (I'm running VS2008 Pro w/ MVC2 targeting .NET 3.5) Just start up a new MVC2 project and paste the following into the `HomeController` over whatever is already there:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Configuration;

namespace BackButtonTest.Controllers
{
    [HandleError]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private string MESSAGE = "Message";
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData[MESSAGE] = HttpRuntime.Cache.Get(MESSAGE);
            Configuration Config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            Config.AppSettings.Settings.Add("SomeKey", "SomeValue");
            Config.Save();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            HttpRuntime.Cache[MESSAGE] = "This is pulled from the HttpRuntime.Cache";
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Then follow these steps:

1. Start-up the app in debug mode.
2. Click on the "About" link. This loads a string into the Cache.
3. Click on the "Home" link. String is pulled from the Cache and stuck in ViewMessage dictionary. Some key/value pair is written to web.config and saved. String from cache should appear on the Home page.
4. Click on the "Home" link again. String *should* be pulled from the cache, but it's not.
5. Stop program. Comment out the 3 lines that start with "Config". Restart the program.
6. Try steps 1 thru 4 again. Notice how the HttpRuntime.Cache has not been emptied.

Weird, huh?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Writing to your web.config will force the application to restart, and, most likely, events for emptying the cache, in-proc sessionstate etc. will go off. Try and write down some log in global.asax Application_End (or whatever the name of the method is :) )

Comment: Wild. I had no idea that writing to web.config would re-start the app.